# Python 3.x How to find the youngest files based on filename 4000+ files

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, filenames

I'm trying to find all the youngest files in a folder based on the filename, i have over 4000 backup files from various site locations with different dates in the filename (see below).

**Sample filename:** *location-model-extra-MMM-DD-YY-HH-MM-SSS*

e.g. xxxx-xx (sitename) is not consistent so can't use character counting and "-" dashes vary due to names, so very inconsistent. The only consistent part is the date using this format *MMM-DD-YY*

```
 \pathto\Dir\

xxx-xx-xx-Apr-24-20-3-29-22
xxx-xx-xx-Feb-2-07-3-22-02-33-40
xxx-xx-xx-Jul-24-20-19-20-11
yyyyyyy-yy-Apr-24-20-3-29-22
yyyyyyy-yy-Feb-2-07-3-22-02-33-40
yyyyyyy-yy-Jul-24-20-19-20-11
ZZ-zz-zZzZZZZZZZ-Apr-24-20-3-29-22
ZZ-zz-zZzZZZZZZZ-Feb-2-07-3-22-02-33-40
ZZ-zz-zZzZZZZZZZ-Jul-24-20-19-20-11

What I'm trying to find is: 

xxx-xx-xx-Jul-24-20-19-20-11
yyyyyyy-yy-Jul-24-20-19-20-11
ZZ-zz-zZzZZZZZZZ-Jul-24-20-19-20-11
```

This is what I have tried but its limited to just returning the over all youngest, was also looking at Dictionaries but don't know how they work for this. So currently stuck on the next steps.

```
filelist = glob.glob(path) 

# print youngest / oldests
list_of_files = glob.glob(path) # * means all if need specific format then *.csv
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file)
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a slightly different route, and added ctime finding the youngest file:

This is the only way I could figure it out, I'm 100 sure there is a more pythonic way to do it.

```
import re
import collections
import os
import platform
import os.path, time
import datetime

# sort based on file meta data... filename stamp  does not include year... 
# %H.%M.%S
today = datetime.datetime.strptime(time.ctime(),"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y") #%H.%M.%S" - time, not needed currently
delta = today -datetime.timedelta(days=30)
print("Today is: " ,today)
print("Delta of 30: " , delta)

dir = "./config/" #"./config/"
path = "C:\PKG\devNetOp\Python\Switch\tmp\*"

# initilize dict
confFileDict = {} 
confFileDict['hosts'] = {} 
cnt1 = 0
pattern = r"[ADFJMNOS]\w*-[\d]{1,2}-[\d]{1,2}" # look for *-MMM-DD
pattern2 = r"[ADFJMNOS]\w*--[\d]{1,2}" # look for *--MMM-DD

footmp = []
nameList = []
counter = 0
errorList = []

# add all filenames to a list; then add all extracted names from filenames to confFileDict{}

def collectFiles(dir):
    global counter
    global confFileDict
    cnt1 = 0
    
    for x in os.listdir(dir): 
        # time restriction for any over that 1 month.
        fctime = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(dir+x))
        if datetime.datetime.strptime(fctime,"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y") > delta:
            nameList.append("{},{}".format(datetime.datetime.strptime(fctime,"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"),x))
        try:
            tmp = re.findall(pattern, x)[0]
        except:
            tmp = re.findall(pattern2, x)[0]
        
        tmp1 = x.split(tmp) 
        confFileDict['hosts'][tmp1[0].strip()] = {}
        if tmp1[0] in x: # match tmp[0] hostname from file 
            if tmp1[0] not in confFileDict: # if hostname is not in Dict than add. 
                    confFileDict['hosts'][tmp1[0]] = x  # add filename into confFileDict
                    counter += 1
        print("hostname updates {}".format(counter), end="\r")
        
    print("total files {} in {}".format(counter, dir))

    counter = 0

    # sort and find most recent file.
    for name in list(confFileDict['hosts'].keys()): # print hostnames
        confFileDict['hosts'][name] = {}
        for j in nameList: # split list nameList[(name,ctime),(name,ctime),...]
            x = j.split(",") # x[0] = ctime stamp / # x[1] = name
            try:
                tmp = re.findall(pattern, x[1])[0] # look for pattern to match date in file  
            except:
                tmp = re.findall(pattern2, x[1])[0] # look for pattern2 to match date in file, same as pattern but incluedes an extra -

            tmp1 = x[1].split(tmp) # spliting hostname out of filename          
            
            if name.startswith(tmp1[0]): # checking if filename matches name in dictionanry of the hostname
                footmp.append((x)) # if yes, add string as a list to temporary list. 
                counter += 1
            
            print("Dict updates {} Errors {} ".format(counter,len(errorList)), end="\r") # counter only file names added to Dict

        footmp.sort() # 
        confFileDict['hosts'][name]={}
        # print("Dict updates {} ".format(counter), end="\r")
        try:
            confFileDict['hosts'][name][footmp[-1][1]] = {}
            confFileDict['hosts'][name][footmp[-1][1]]['ctime'] = footmp[-1][0] 
            confFileDict['hosts'][name]['Error'] = "None"   
        except: # if error is thrown, most likely that the files don't meet the time criteria for time delta (30 days) 
            # print("{} has no valid files or backsup older than 30 days".format(name)) # print errors
            confFileDict['hosts'][name]['Error'] = "backups older than 30days"          
            errorList.append(name) # only used for counting file names
            # print("Dict updates with Errors {} ".format(len(errorList), end="\r"))
        del footmp[:]                           
    

    print("Total names {} in Dict {}".format(counter, len(confFileDict.keys())))
    print("No. of switches without dates files. {} ".format(len(errorList)))

collectFiles(dir)
del errorList[:]
del nameList [:]
# return list if filenames that match the youngest files. 
for i in list(confFileDict['hosts'].keys()):
    if list(confFileDict['hosts'][i].keys())[0] != 'Error':
        print(i)
```